# Ubuntu 20.04 Wifi extremely slow

Tags: networking, drivers

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 a week back with a dual boot with Windows10. My purpose of installing Ubuntu was that it does not create issues frequently unlike Windows10. Now coming to the point WiFi on Ubuntu is giving a speed of 5Mbps when just booted and after that <0.5Mbps. Browsing is fast but download is slow. On the other hand Windows10 is giving a speed of 20Mbps on the same PC and WiFi. I have updated the software many times. My WiFi driver according to terminal is Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak]. My kernel version for Ubuntu is 5.4.0-33-generic.

I have done all this:

1. sudo apt remove backport-iwlwifi-dkms
2. /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf and changed the value from 3 to 2,        saved changes and rebooted.

All this is not helping

I don't know much about wireless systems but Intel website shows that for kernel 5.2+ I should be using Intel® Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz driver.

And the software Updater is showing no additional drivers.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the kernel which suites you the best from [https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/)

Follow the below link to learn how to install kernel in your system.
https://linuxhint.com/update_ubuntu_kernel_20_04/